# ssh connect to OracleLinux8 response:Bad packet length 2424479189. Connection corrupted

Tags: 22.04, ssh

**ssh-client:**

```
uname -a :5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
```

**ssh-server:**

```
Oracle Linux Server 8.9"
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
```

```
userxxx@userxxx-H3C-X7-030s-0274:~$ ssh 192.168.xxx.xxx -vvv
......
debug1: Host '192.168.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/userxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 2 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/userxxx/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:8/LUiKki9kVQBQgKvBlVs67wsC834tokLw04csky8d4 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/userxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:wfU6LbhyFJZ4EE5af/vaBMBxRo/xOf2DrVLKZJxGCqQ agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/userxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/userxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/userxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/userxxx/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/userxxx/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
Bad packet length 2424479189.
debug2: sshpkt_disconnect: sending SSH2_MSG_DISCONNECT: Packet corrupt
debug3: send packet: type 1
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection corrupted
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1828501/how-to-solve-ssh-connection-corrupted-error/1828506 Try this solution. It solved mine